# How to delete tags with backslashs in subversion?

Tags: git, svn, migration, backslash

I am converting a svn repository to git. During the process of "git svn clone" the process crashed.
The reason was that a tag name contains a number of backslashes (full directory path in windows notation). It is not possible to delete or rename this tag.

Any ideas how I can delete that wrong tag? Any dirty tricks with subversion database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot easily delete that tag in the SVN repo, then try again your migration using [subgit import](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7)

[SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) has a free offer for import, and it generally is more robust than [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn): it might better handle that tag.
Once converted, you can try and delete it in the Git repo itself.

Comment: This tool made my day ;-)

Comment: @codelab Great! Send you thanks to Alexander Kitaev: he created and maintained SubGit. Listen more at http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/09/gitminutes-22-alexander-kitaev-about.html.